# How to set a minimum and maximum limit for a date picker in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm working on an app in which i'm using a custom date and time picker.
I've created a dialog box and inside that i'm showing date and time picker respectively now I want to set a minimum and maximum limit for the date picker.
Such as one should not be able to select the previous date from today and not more than a month ahead. 
This is my code

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            final DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(getActivity());
            try {
                Field f[] = picker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : f) {
                    if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker") || field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner")) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        Object yearPicker = new Object();
                        yearPicker = field.get(picker);
                        ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
            picker.setMinDate(new  Date().getTime());

            builder.setTitle("Please select date on which you would be leaving :")
                    .setView(picker)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
                                    Date date1 = new Date();
                                    date1.setDate(picker.getDayOfMonth());
                                    date1.setMonth(picker.getMonth());
                                    final String s = parseFormat.format(date1);
                                    Log.e("DATE", s);
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                                    Date date2=new Date();
                                    date2.setDate(picker.getDayOfMonth());
                                    date2.setMonth(picker.getMonth());
                                    final String s2=sdf.format(date2);


                                    //Time picker
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    final TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(getActivity());
                                    picker.setIs24HourView(true);
                                    builder.setTitle("Please select time at which you would be leaving :")
                                            .setView(picker)
                                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                            int hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
                                                            int minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
                                                            leaving.setTextSize(14);

                                                            leaving.setText(s + " " + hour + ":" + minute);
                                                            inTime=s2+" "+hour+":"+minute;
                                                            Log.e("inTime ",inTime);
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                    leaving.setText("");
                                                    inTime="";
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }).create().show();
                                    //Time picker
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    leaving.setText("");
                                    inTime="";
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .create().show();
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: for setting minimum date you can use `datePickerobject.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);`

Comment: for maximum `datePickerobject.setMaxDate(lastdate_converted_in_long);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, This shows from today to next 5 year date in datepicker dialog.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtDatePicker;
    Calendar cal,cal1;
    long maxDate;
    Date date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

        txtDatePicker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDatePicker);
        txtDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+arg1+"/"+(arg2+1)+"/"+arg3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. 
I use this code in my application.

```
    // Global declaration

    Calendar preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar preferDate2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    private int year, month, day;


    // here preferredDate1 and preferredDate2 are textview
    preferredDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, prefferedDate1Picker, preferDate1
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), preferDate1.get(Calendar.MONTH), preferDate1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dp.show();
                }
            });

    private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener prefferedDate1Picker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
                preferredDate2.setText("");
                preferredDate1.setText((selectedDay < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(selectedDay) : String.valueOf(selectedDay)) + "/"
                        + (selectedMonth + 1 < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)) : String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)))
                        + "/" + selectedYear);

            }
        };


// This will set date based on preferredDate1
// change here according to your need. If you want to add or remove one month then set based on data. In this I add one day in second data picker.
preferredDate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerDialog dp2 = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, prefferedDate2Picker, preferDate2
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), preferDate2.get(Calendar.MONTH), preferDate2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    long mili = preferDate1.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000L;
                    dp2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mili);
                    dp2.show();

            }
        });

        private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener prefferedDate2Picker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            preferDate2 = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay+1);
            preferredDate2.setText((selectedDay < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(selectedDay) : String.valueOf(selectedDay)) + "/"
                    + (selectedMonth + 1 < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)) : String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)))
                    + "/" + selectedYear);

        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . I'm using setMinDate() function. It is showing the previous dates in shaded color but if I click on those dates  they are being selected. And Please tell me how to use setMaxDate() for a month period

Comment: I made some changes in my existing and now its working for MinDate but how to add for max date?

Comment: wokring but how to add for a month ahead

Comment: See my updated code and tell me if any error or problems occurred.